# いい試合順にランク付けするアルゴリズム

Tags: アルゴリズム

スポーツ等の複数の試合をリアルタイムにいい試合順にランク付けするプログラムを作成しています。

いい試合の基準として、時間が大きくかつ点差が小さいものがいい試合だと考えれれます。
つまり、x軸を時間y軸を点差とした時に、試合の1時的な情報の集合を取得し、時間、点差を正規化し、グラフを描画した時に右下にある試合がいい試合(時間が経過しているのに点差が開いていない)ということになり、左上にある試合(時間が短いのに点差が開いている)が悪い試合になります。

この順位を取得するにはどのようなアルゴリズムを使用すればいいでしょうか。

Comment: この定義のままだと、試合終了時の得点差だけでよい試合かどうかが決まってしまいますね。引き分けの試合が最高の試合となります(^^;シーソゲームの方が一般的には楽しいのでは？フーリエ変換して高い周波数成分が出ているのをよしとするとか。発想をまったく変えて、線形回帰問題としても良いかも。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。私もシーソーゲームがいい試合だと言えると思います。しかし今回作成しようとしているアプリケーションでは試合情報をリアルタイム(外部API)で取得し、なおかつWebアプリケーションでの運用を前提としているので頻繁なデータ取得、時系列のデータ収集ができないため、このようなアルゴリズムを検討しています。あと、ゲームはサッカーや野球等の点数が数分に1回しか変わらないようなゲームではなく点数がめまぐるしく変わるゲーム、例えばバスケット等を想定しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ただ計算するだけなら．ある時点でのi番目の試合の経過時間をt_i，点差をd_iとして，スコアd_i/t_iが一番ちいさな試合を選ぶ．ただしd_i/t_iが同じものが複数ある場合があるので，その場合はt_iが大きなものを選ぶ．でよいですか?

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。確かにこの方法でできそうですね。

Answer (score 0):

1つ自分で考えました。

点差を正規化するときに基準を最小値にすると、時間に対して点差が反比例するグラフをかけるのでそれをベクトルの大きさを求める公式でランク付けする。

他にもいい方法があれば教えて下さい。